# How to remove the effect of confounding variables in sparse linear models?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, graphical-model, confounding

I would like to build sparse linear regression model, but I would like to remove the effect of (hidden) confounding variables that control the input features and output variables jointly. I was looking at a clear way of incorporating this into my formulation. More specifically, given confounding factor Z, maybe my input feature and output variable become independent, but without removing the effect of Z, my linear model tends to select that specific feature.
More specifically, if X is my feature and Y is output variable, 
the dependencies between them might exist in the form of 
$Z->X$, $Z->Y$, If I build a linear regression model of $Y=\beta X + \epsilon$, then $\beta$ will be more probably non-zero, because variable $Z$ control both $X$ and $Y$. If I find a way to incorporate these into my model, then $\beta$ will be zero.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? Is the relationship between the input-output-hidden variables of the form Y = AX + Z?

Comment: Please edit your question to mention that you've simultaneously cross-posted this question at 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841256/how-to-remove-the-effect-of-confounding-variables-in-sparse-linear-models
And if you accept an answer at one forum, please mention that at the other forum so folks can spend time on questions that have yet to be answered.

Comment: In general you would want to avoid this situation, conduct a randomized trial to negate the effects of confounding variables. If this is not possible, then you could try to de-correlate your sample to diminish the confounding effect, for ex. bootstrap.